# How to fix user input in time only text field using javascript (on blur)

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery, jquery-mask

I am trying to find solution for the following scenrio:
- I have a `textinput` field where user can enter only time in format like (`01:00 or 13:00`).
- If user enter just `13` on blur it should be fixed to: `13:00`
- or `1` should be fixed to `01:00`
- or `135` should be fixed to `01:05`
It would be great if this can be done via `JavaScript` only but I have tried something with `jquery` and `mask` plugin just can't finish it to make explained scenario:

My [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uqu3n/)

```
$("#time").blur(function() {       
    var userInput = $(this).val().replace(/^([0-9])([0-9]):([0-9])_$/, "0$1:$2$3");     
    if(!userInput.match(/([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]/)){

    }else{
        $(this).val(userInput);
        return true;
    };
}).mask("99:99");
```

Comment: Why is `135` -> `01:05` and not `13:05` or `01:35`?

Comment: Right it should be 13:05 my mistake.

Comment: why would you even allow `135` as a valid time? Not a format that people would read intuitively to be `01:05`

Comment: No..no if user enter fields in hurry he can enter 135 and on blur that should be instantly changed to 13:05 so user doesn't have to worry.

Comment: at some point you can't accept users making errors...if it doesn't fit...tell them

Comment: But my request is not to popup alert and tell them format is invalid. Request is if user enter wrong to script fix it to the best value. So if he enter...I don't know `1345 => (onblur) 13:45, 13 => 13:00, 134 => 13:04, 015 => 01:05`. I also check this on server side I for user experience bla bla script should replace wrong format with valid format.